# Update value with value in another row of same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need help with the following SQL:-

```
UPDATE `mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS t1 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity`
AS t2 ON t1.`entity_id`= t2.`entity_id`
SET t1.`value` = CONCAT('US Sports Goods ', t1.`value`, ' | My Site Name') 
WHERE t2.`path` LIKE '1/2642%' AND t2.`level` > 1 AND t1.`attribute_id` = 40
```

My problem is that the `t1.value` field in the `CONCAT()` statement needs to pull the `t1.value` WHERE `t1.attribute_id = 35` and I am struggling to figure out how to correctly specify this within the `CONCAT()` statement.

Comment: Note, your question states `WHERE t1.attribute_id = 35` but your code states `WHERE ... AND t1.attribute_id = 40`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Snap! ;-)

Comment: For all rows in `mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar` where t2.`path` LIKE '1/2642%' AND t2.`level` > 1 AND t1.`attribute_id` = 40, I need to set the `value` field equal to the value stored on the `value` field from the row in the same `mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE t2.`path` LIKE '1/2642%' AND t2.`level` > 1 AND t1.`attribute_id` = 35.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS t1 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity`
AS t2 ON t1.`entity_id`= t2.`entity_id`
SET t1.`value` = CONCAT('US Sports Goods ', (SELECT t3.`value` FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS t3 WHERE t3.`attribute_id` = 35 LIMIT 1), ' | My Site Name') 
WHERE t2.`path` LIKE '1/2642%' AND t2.`level` > 1 AND t1.`attribute_id` = 40
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this gives the error:- #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Iswanto, I have posted the error message above i.e. #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS t1 
INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity` AS t2 ON t1.`entity_id`= t2.`entity_id`
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT *
   FROM mg_catalog_category_entity_varchar
   WHERE `attribute_id` = 35
) AS t12 ON t2.entity_id = t12.entity_id 
SET t1.`value` = CONCAT('US Sports Goods ', t12.`value`, ' | My Site Name') 
WHERE t2.`path` LIKE '1/2642%' 
  AND t2.`level` > 1 
  AND t1.`attribute_id` = 40
```

Comment: That worked perfectly Mahmoud. Many thanks for the quick response and solution.